# Outputting raw xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on a script for merging multiple rss feeds into one using php..my aim is to have the merged feeds display as ONE RAW XML file

here's my code for the merge:

```
$feeds = array(
    'http://feed1',
    'http://feed2',
    );

$entries = array();

foreach ($feeds as $feed) 
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/rss//item'));
    //var_dump ($xml);exit;
}

usort($entries, function ($x, $y)
 {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
 });


print_r($entries);
```

doing a print_r for the above code gives me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => New Jersey Celebrates 'Bacon Week' [description] => Bacon lovers visiting Atlantic City. (Feb. 11) [guid] => 3028082 [pubDate] => Tue, 11 Feb 2014 06:28:53 GMT [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [length] => 18656689 [type] => video/quicktime [url] => http://mediafilename/news-video/MMFWot0BJ0-3RNi7Anmvpw-853x480-1.mov ) ) ).....
```

my desire is to have a proper xml file displayed(raw xml) with all the various xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the instance to xml and send the correct header before. Try this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print $entries->asXML();
```

More information here:
http://www.php.net/manual/it/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: hello Marc..is that all there is i.e just insert those two lines in my code?(header at the top and print at the end??)

Comment: instead of: print_r($entries); I don't checked the other code, expect that it works ;-)